# Rotate border - bad quality

Tags: html, css, border

I have a circle element with half a border, when its hovered the border animate to cover the whole circle.

My problem is that the border appears with bad quality, pixelated.
Any way to get around this?

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/v0Lkq320/2/)

I did this all with CSS, using the following code:

```
.circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 2px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.69);
    -moz-box-shadow:    3px 2px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.69);
    box-shadow:         3px 2px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.69);
    height: 180px;
    width: 180px;
    margin: 9px auto;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.arc_q {
    position: absolute;
    top: -7px;
    left: -7px;
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-width: 7px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-image: none;

    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);

}

.arc_q_2 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-135deg);
    transform: rotate(-135deg);

}
.arc_q_3 {
    -webkit-transition: all 400ms;
    -moz-transition: all 400ms;
    transition: all 400ms;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-135deg);
    transform: rotate(-135deg);
}
.arc_q_4 {
    -webkit-transition: all 400ms;
    -moz-transition: all 400ms;
    transition: all 400ms;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-135deg);
    transform: rotate(-135deg);
}


.circle:hover .arc_q_3 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-225deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-225deg);
    transform: rotate(-225deg);


}
.circle:hover .arc_q_4 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-315deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-315deg);
    transform: rotate(-315deg);

}

#circle_1 .arc_q {
    border-color: #e01f25 transparent transparent transparent;
}

#circle_1 .circle {
    background-image: url('images/adegamae_logo.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-size: 80px;
}
```

Comment: This might be because you have multiple red circles overlapping each other. The edges are fading to transparent. Multiple half-transparent elements slightly become less transparent. If you hover over your circle, when the animation starts you can see the circle moving and clearing the edges again, and thus becoming smoother. What you should try: Hide all overlapping elements.

Comment: Yes, i've noticed that, I tried to hide the overlapping elements with opacity. They would stay with 0 opacity while iddle, on hover they would switch to 1 and animate, it still looks weird as you notice the elements overlapping this way also, and this way I cant make the elements animate back, when hovered out... example : https://jsfiddle.net/v0Lkq320/3/

Comment: I thought of an element to hide the lower layers, something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/v0Lkq320/5/ (simple solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AlexG's fiddle can be further simplified by making each div take up half the circle, requiring only two arc divs plus one to hide elements.  Consider using:

```
border-color: #e01f25 transparent transparent #e01f25;
```

instead of

```
border-color: #e01f25 transparent transparent transparent;
```

See the follow fiddle for an example: https://jsfiddle.net/38d47ag0/

It may also be noted that I am only transitioning the `transform` property, since that is the only one that is changing.

Comment: Nice. Looking good, and ye, makes sense no need for the 4 arcs ;) .. Thanks